# I am trying to configure google SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to configure google SMTP but everytime I am getting SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed error, I've tried multiple solutions but nothing is working here. How to enable smtp mail service. here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Send email via Gmail SMTP server in PHP</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Send Email via Gmail SMTP Server in PHP</h1>
        <div id="login">
            <h2>Send Email</h2>
            <hr/>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Gmail ID" name="email"/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Gmail Password" name="password"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="To : Email Id " name="toid"/>  
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject : " name="subject"/>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Your Message..." name="message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send"/>
            </form>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

        require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){      
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  //Enable SMTP debugging. 
            $mail->isSMTP();/*Set mailer to use SMTP*/
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';/*Specify main and backup SMTP servers*/
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;/*Enable SMTP authentication*/
            $mail->Username = $email;/*SMTP username*/
            $mail->Password = $password;/*SMTP password*/
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';/*Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted*/
            $mail->From = 'abc';
            //$mail->FromName = $name;
            $mail->addAddress('mmmmmm@gmail.com', 'demo');/*Add a recipient*/
            //$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
            /*$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');*/
            /*$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');*/
            $mail->WordWrap = 70;/*DEFAULT = Set word wrap to 50 characters*/
            $mail->addAttachment('../tmp/' . $varfile, $varfile);/*Add attachments*/
            /*$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');*/
            /*$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');*/
            $mail->isHTML(true);/*Set email format to HTML (default = true)*/
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body    = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
            $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
            if(!$mail->send()){
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }else{
                header("Location: http://cetpatechnologies.com/mail/index.php");
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, that's why posted here.

Comment: When I commented out the following lines it seemed like working
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->addAttachment('../tmp/' . $varfile, $varfile);

Comment: Did you look at [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)?  Andy debug output?

Comment: @veniseis yes! 
SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 p74sm1721995lfp.68 - gsmtp 2017-03-02 13:33:58 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14

Comment: Did you read the error message in that debug output?